# Will it be possible to remove/add indicator-* applets from panel without using synaptic?

Tags: unity, indicator, gnome-panel, customization

Will it be possible to remove/add indicator-* applets from the panel without using synaptic?

Not installing, just adding/removing installed ones. Now in ubuntu 10.10 we can't remove one applet alone like indicator-messages without uninstalling it or removing all related/grouped indicators.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can, you go remove the .desktop files for the non-desired options somewhere deep in /usr/share/applications/indicator-me or something along that line... best not to fool w/ it too much.

Comment: I removed my answer, this is pretty much what I meant =)

Comment: it was a good answer, maybe i should have added the location details as a comment to yours...

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the panel, "Add to panel"
Right click on the applet "Remove from panel"
But if you mean installing new applets like in kde, my answer is no. So far gnome 3 has no applet support.

Comment: gnome 3? 10.10 doesn't have gnome 3... -_-