# How can I start indicator-messages manually?

Tags: indicator, indicator-message

I cannot find the executable for `indicator-messages`.

I would like to run it manually for debugging purposes.

Can someone help me to locate it, please?

Comment: Is this a little same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/14607/how-to-refresh-indicators this link?

Comment: None of the methods mentioned there works for me.

Comment: I am a beginner, but I've tried to remove indicator-message from unity-panel and xfce indicator-messages, I don't know the version you are running. http://askubuntu.com/questions/10739/will-it-be-possible-to-remove-add-indicator-applets-from-panel-without-using-s Can this help you? After I add/remove, I need to restart the service, in my memory.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I don't have any indicator application under `/usr/share/applications/`.

Comment: I see `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/` two text files in it, they refer  `/usr/share/applications/pidgin.desktop` and `/usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop`And open `dconf-editor` com>canonical>indicator>messages name:applications value:pidgin.desktop Perhaps,I need to do with these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the content of the `indicator-messages.desktop` file (located in `/etc/xdg/autostart`) you can see that the "executable file" is a service which is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service`, what mainly means you can't launch `indicator-messages` manually, just because it's not an executable application such as `gedit`.

Concerning the comment `an application with id 'liferea.desktop' is not installed`, check if `gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.messages applications` returns correct entries of applications being installed such as the default setting `['thunderbird.desktop']`.
When you prefer to use a GUI based tool - you can do it with `dconf-editor` as well of course.

Comment: Thank you so much! This revealed an interesting insight:  `$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service

(process:17035): Indicator-Messages-WARNING **: an application with id 'liferea.desktop' is not installed`